# Using Max() in where query to find most recent date in a table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables Clients and Notes, in the notes table I record all activity for a client. What I am trying to do is query the notes table to find which clients haven't had any activity in the past 30 days.

After spending a good potion of last night and this morning I havent been able to find a working solution.. Any suggestions?

```
SELECT  `c`.`ClientID` , `c`.`CompanyName` , MAX(  `NtWhen` ) 
FROM  `clients` AS  `c` 
JOIN  `client-notes` AS  `n` ON (  `c`.`ClientID` =  `n`.`NtClient` ) 
WHERE  `NtText` =  'Viewed Client Details'
AND  MAX(`NtWhen`) < '2012-04-10'
GROUP BY  `NtClient` 
ORDER BY MAX(`NtWhen`) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle is that you need to group your notes table by client, and then filter those groups (i.e. use `HAVING`) for only those in which the most recent date was before 30 days ago:

```
SELECT   NtClient
FROM     `client-notes`
GROUP BY NtClient
HAVING   MAX(NtWhen) < DATESUB(NOW(), 30)
```

You can join with your `clients` table as you were before if you need the company name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT  `c`.`ClientID` , `c`.`CompanyName` , MAX(  `NtWhen` ) 
  FROM  `clients` AS  `c` 
  JOIN  `client-notes` AS  `n` ON (  `c`.`ClientID` =  `n`.`NtClient` ) 
 WHERE  `NtText` =  'Viewed Client Details'
 GROUP BY  `NtClient` 
HAVING MAX(`NtWhen`) < '2012-04-10'
 ORDER BY MAX(`NtWhen`) DESC;
```